# Proof by Induction of the sum of heights of nodes in a full binary tree

Tags: tree, proof

I'm trying to prove the following by induction:

```
sum(k*2^(H-k), k = 0 .. H) = N-H-1
```

it's a problem for an algorithms class. I was thinking I could do what I normally do for summations, which is to assume that it works for some P(m) and then increment the sum for P(m+1) and work backwards by adding to the right side what the additional summation on the left side produces.

But, this problem is different because substituting H+1 changes each term inside of the summation... so I don't think that technique will work.

This is a homework problem... so I'm obviously not expecting a complete solution. But, I'm not really sure where to take the summation so I'm looking for other ways of doing the induction.

Comment: what is N in the given equation?

Comment: my bad! N is the number of nodes in the tree (given by the equation N=2^(H+1)-1). H is the height of the tree (assuming a tree that's just the root is height 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the tree is full, you can still do a somewhat traditional proof by induction. Just write that if it works for some height `H`, then you know the sum of heights is `N-H-1` for that height; then try it for height `H+1`. Consider:

- What's the new sum of all the nodes in the old tree (i.e. what does `N-H-1` become)?
- What heights are added with the new level of nodes in the full tree?